# Oracle 11g - Adding a Total Column to a Pivot Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot-table

I've created a pivot table with data from multiple tables (using JOINS).  How can I add another column to the table which adds up each column from each row?

Example:

```
Category  |  A  |  B  |  C |
ABC          1     1     1
A            1     0     0
B            0     1     0
C            0     0     1


Category  |  A  |  B  |  C | TOTAL
ABC          1     1     1    3
A            1     0     0    1
B            0     1     0    1 
C            0     0     1    1
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have written a query that produces the first set of results (possibly as a result of a `pivot` statement in the `select`)?  Or are you saying that you have a table (a physical object persisted in the database) with the first set of data?

Answer (score 0):

```
SCOTT@research 15-APR-15> select * from testing ;

CATEG          A          B          C
----- ---------- ---------- ----------
ABC            1          1          1
A              1          0          0
B              0          1          0
C              0          0          1

SCOTT@research 15-APR-15> select category,a,b,c, sum(a+b+c) as "total" from testing group by category,a,b,c order by category;

CATEG          A          B          C      total
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A              1          0          0          1
ABC            1          1          1          3
B              0          1          0          1
C              0          0          1          1
```

In case you want to add a column, then can add one use a procedure to update the values using this,

```
alter table testing add total int;
```

use this procedure to update the values

```
create or replace procedure add_Test
is
sqlis varchar2(10);
total1 int;
begin
for i in (select * from testing) loop
  select sum(a+b+c) into total1 from testing where category=i.category;
 update testing set total=total1 where category=i.category;
 end loop;
 commit;
 end;


exec add_test;

SCOTT@research 15-APR-15> select * from testing;

CATEG          A          B          C      TOTAL
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
ABC            1          1          1          3
A              1          0          0          1
B              0          1          0          1
C              0          0          1          1
```